# How do I redirect from BuddyPress component for non logged in user

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, buddypress

I have a specific use case where I want to show non logged in users BuddyPress Members and Groups in the sidebar of a public page, but when a user clicks on a member or group (or any BP component) I want to redirect them to the Register page.

I have been successful with the below code in my functions.php file to redirect based on the slug of the /members and /groups page, however I cannot figure out how to make it work either for /groups/group-a or members/member-a, etc or better yet for all BuddyPress components.

The end goal is that when a non logged in user navigates to any BuddyPress component they are redirected to my register page.

```
//custom redirect for non logged in users
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );
function redirect_to_specific_page() {
if ( is_page( array( 'groups', 'members') ) && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
wp_redirect( 'http:mysite.com/register', 301 );
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the BP widgets for members and groups, then the issue is the `while` loop for those widgets.  Take a look at them and how they include links in the loop.

The best solution is to write custom widgets that use loops that use a conditional to create a link for the member or group.  And then you don't need your `template_redirect` function.